# What changed on the {{action}} behavior since RC3.1 that breaks the ember.js todo code

Tags: ember.js

Im currently working through the Ember.js Getting started Guide, but i'm using v1.0.0-rc.6.3 instead of RC3.1 as mentioned in the Guide.

Now i reached the chapter about implementing the editing of single todos, but the {{action}} handler implemented in the Guide dosn't seem to work, so my fist assumption is that the behavior of events changed.

Here is my code so far in a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ogixej/1/edit

As you can see, when you double click a todo item a error is raised in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'editTodo'.
```

Could you tell me what changed an how i'm supposed to do it in a correct manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `TodoController` is the controller responsible for the items you need to define this on your `TodosController`, like this:

```
Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'todo',
  ...
});
```

This way the `editTodo` function is correctly invoked. Here your working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogixej/6/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer i was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize that this should be a comment, but my reputation is too low, yet.

While @intuitivePixel's answer is correct, and accepted, it did not work for me later in the example, during the Transitioning examples ([Getting Started Guide - Adding Child Routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/adding-child-routes/)).  Once I broke the templates apart, I had to move the `itemController` property from the controller and into the template, during the `{{#each}}`, like so:

```
{{#each itemController="todo"}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

If you look closely, you can find this code in Ember's first example block, but it's not called out in the surrounding narrative, so I missed it.